# Resolving symbols in :require'd namespace

Tags: clojure

I'm writing a small application that includes a password change function with validators for password quality.  Currently the validators are specified in a map like so:

```lisp
(def validations
  {:min-length 6
   :max-length 32})
```

The validations map is defined in the validations namespace, but I plan to move it to a configuration namespace later on. My decision to use a map in this way was to make configuration straight-forward for non-programmers.

There are a number of validation functions in the validations namespace that usually take the form:

```lisp
(defn min-length [n s]
  {:req (str "be at least " n " characters long")
   :pass? (>= (.length (or s "")) n)})
```

So with the function above `(min-length 3 "clojure")` would return `{:req "be at least 3 characters long", :pass? true}`.

I can validate a password with this function in the validation namespace with this function:

```lisp
(defn validate-new-password [password]
  (into {} (for [[k v] validations]
             [k (eval (list (-> k name symbol) v password))])))
```

The result being something like:

```lisp
>(validate-new-password "clojure")
{:min-length {:req "be at least 6 characters long", :pass? true}, 
 :max-length {:req "be no longer than 32 characters long", :pass? true}, 
 :min-digits {:req "have at least 1 digit", :pass? false},  
 :allow-whitespace {:req "not contain spaces or tabs", :pass? true}, 
 :allow-dict-words {:req "not be a dictionary word", :pass? false}}
```

What is the most practical way to resolve the validation functions when the validate-new-password function is called from outside the validation namespace?

I've tried a number of approaches over the past weeks but I've never been happy with the resulting form (and none of them have worked!).

Generally I guess the question is "how are symbols in a :require'd namespace resolved when called by functions within that namespace?"

I'm also interested on any general comments about my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for eval, as in 98% of the cases.

```
(defn validate-new-password
  [password]
  (into {} (for [[k v] validations]
             [k ((->> k name (symbol "your.name.space") resolve) v password)])))
```

Comment: Thanks to you and Michal for your answers. Yes, eval was less than ideal. Your solution of course worked, though I was hoping to avoid the need to specify the namespace explicitly. I believe I understand why it is required with my implementation, but is it possible to remove? I don't expect the configuration to change during runtime, so can I use a macro to compose a wrapper function at compile time? If so, would I be able to use the partial function on each of my validation functions (all args except the string input)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the general question (from the penultimate paragraph of the question), symbols are normally resolved at compile time -- you have to go out of your way (that is, use `resolve`<sup>1</sup>) to postpone resolution to runtime.

That said, you probably don't need to postpone resolution in this case, you simply need to `:require` the configuration namespace in the validations namespace and refer to `config/validations` in the relevant spot.

A minor complication would arise if you wanted your config namespace to depend on the validations namespace (i.e. `:require` or `:use` it itself, or else another namespace which depends on it). In that case you could provide a handful of configuration setters in the validations namespace and use those from config. E.g.:

```
(def validations (atom default-validations))
(defn set-validations! [vs]   (reset! validations vs))
(defn add-validation!  [k v]  (swap! validations assoc k v))
```

Then put `@validations` in place of `validations` in `validate-new-password`.

Alternatively, you could put your default validations in a Var and provide functions to rebind the Var (presumably this will only need to happen once, or else very rarely, so using a Var shouldn't be a problem):

```
(def validations default-validations)
(defn set-validations! [vs]  (.bindRoot validations vs))
(defn add-validation!  [k v] (alter-var-root validations assoc k v))
```

Now if you actually cannot predict, at the time of writing the code, which namespace you'll need to resolve your symbol in, then kotarak's answer (with its use of `resolve`) is the way to go.

---

<sup>1</sup> You could say `eval` also allows you to do it, although technically it performs compilation at runtime, so symbol resultion in `eval`'d forms still occurs at compilation time. The more important thing to remember about it is that it's hardly ever needed.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed response. I'll experiment with your suggested approach today and see how I go.